# Crossjoin-like operation except A x {} = A?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

Is there a way to implement operation (let's annotate it ∘) that behaves just like regular cross join except for empty sets it returns non empty side.

```
∘ - new operation
x - cross join
{} - empty result set


A ∘ B  = A x B
A ∘ {} = A
{} ∘ B = B
{} ∘ {} = {}
```

Columns of A and B differ and are non empty.

Comment: What should the result of {} ∘ {} be? At a glance I don't think it is possible without resorting to a procedure language. A ∘ B will have the same type regardless of what tuples that exist in either relation.

Comment: Given the accepted answer I assume that {} menas a relation with n attributes and 0 rows, correct? Furthermore = is defined as same number of rows?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Ok, you can then ignore my comment above. I interpreted `{}` to mean 0 columns and 0 rows and `=` as being `union-compatible` and having the same content.

Comment: My bad for not being specific enough. I believe the updated question now avoids all confusion. Thank you for improving it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will this work for you?

```
A FULL OUTER JOIN B ON TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

If by empty set, you mean "that has zero column", then `CROSS JOIN` with an empty SELECT already does that:

```
postgres=# \echo :SERVER_VERSION_NAME 
10.3 (Debian 10.3-1.pgdg90+1)

postgres=# select * from (select 'a') A cross join (select ) B;
 ?column? 
----------
 a
(1 row)
```

Note that the empty select (no column) is a relatively recent addition in PostgreSQL.On older versions, the above query will cause a syntax error.

---

Another interpretation of the question could be that in `A ∘ {}`, A is a table-type with certain columns, and `{}` is a arbitrarily different table-type with different columns but that happens to contain 0 row.
In that case there will be no operation in SQL that satisfies the question, because the **result type** of a query cannot depend on the contents of relations. It must always depend only on the definitions of the relations involved, so that it can be determined without actually running the query.

Comment: Interesting, ( select ) corresponds to DUM?

Comment: @Lennart: I didn't know about DUM, just googled it and it seems that it's more like [DEE](http://wiki.c2.com/?TableDee) because `(select )` returns one row. [DUM](http://wiki.c2.com/?TableDum) would be `(select where false)`.

Comment: Ah, you are right. Very cool, thanks for showing it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. FULL OUTER JOIN on TRUE happens to have correct semantics. I have also specified question so it's not underspecified.